# how to mirror a texture so that its uvs match

Tags: texturing, uv

hi i'm new to editing models and uv maps but i'm trying to edit a model from a nintendo game, it's a simple forklift i'm editing the tire but its uvs are foreign to me http://prntscr.com/igkmgi

[image]

as you can see they go over the edge, what seems to be the case is if the texture were mirrored the uv wouldn't have a problem adjusting to it. problem, i don't know how to make it do so.

someone else asked this question and they were in a similar problem with a different nintendo model, and it was suggested to repeat it in image mapping. I've done so but it only seems to affect the preview and not the actual scene
http://prntscr.com/igknq2

[image]

the uvs are fine, i just want to mirror the texture itself. how do i do that?

Comment: Did you try separting and flipping the other side of the UVs ? Or alternatively you could edit the texture and mirror it in other external programs if you don't want to mess with the UVs.

Comment: i did try editing the texture but that just extended the uvs and there wasn't a way to fix that.
and in the case of the uvs itself i did try flipping them but that's not a desirable option as it's really only the texture that needs mirroring not the uvs going over the edge